# Getting the android context in an adapter

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-context

In many of the code samples that I find on the internet the `context` is obtained in the constructor of an adapter.

This context is used to get an `inflater` to inflate the views in `getView` method.

My Question is why bother getting the context in the constructor when it can easily be obtained like so

```
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(inflater == null){
            Context context = parent.getContext();
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            }
            ...
            ...

            return convertView;
        }
```

Also is there any reason not to use the above method because it till now I have not faced any problem in using it .

Comment: you can directly use `LayoutInflater` by `getLayoutInflater()` of your Activity.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Obtaining the Context in the constructor has (at least) three advantages:

1. You only do it once, not every time, `getView()` is called.
2. You can use it for other purposes too, when needed.
3. It also works, when `parent` is `null`.

However, if you don't have any problems with your solution, you might as well stick to it.

Comment: - I don't get the context every time `getView` is called, only when the inflater is null

 - Personally I have never needed the context anywhere outside `getview`

 - Parent being null seems rare , but this is a valid point

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    Holder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_job, parent, false);
        holder = new Holder(view, this);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (Holder) view.getTag();
    }

    holder.parse(getItem(position), position);
    return view;
}

public class Holder {

    @Bind(R.id.type)
    TextView type;
    @Bind(R.id.date_time)
    TextView dateTime;
    @Bind(R.id.grade)
    TextView grade;

    public Holder(View view) {
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    }

    public void parse(final GetGradeHistoryResponse.GradeHistory item) {
        if (item.grade < 0) {
            grade.setTextColor(App.getInstance()
                    .getResources().getColor(R.color.withdraw_status));
            grade.setText(String.valueOf(item.grade));
        } else {
            grade.setTextColor(App.getInstance()
                    .getResources().getColor(R.color.primary));
            grade.setText("+" + String.valueOf(item.grade));
        }

        type.setText(item.type);
        dateTime.setText(item.datetime);
    }
}
```

You can get context by `view.getContext() in the Holder`

Comment: `view.getContext()` in the Holder is the key for me

Answer (score 3):

**Just simple like this!!**

```
class RecentlyAdapter(var data: List<String>) : Adapter<RecentlyAdapter.HomeViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): HomeViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_recently_played, parent, false)
    return HomeViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return data.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: HomeViewHolder, position: Int) {

}

class HomeViewHolder(itemView: View): ViewHolder(itemView) {
    init {
        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(itemView.context, MusicPlayerActivity::class.java)
            var context = itemView.context
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}

}
```

**To get context use itemView.context**

Answer (score 2):

What if someone will create a class that uses `BaseAdapter` to store Views somewhere (and, maybe, it will attach them to parent later)? In this case `parent` may be `null`.

It's not such a big problem, decide for yourself what is better.

For example:

```
public class MockWithAdapter{

    private BaseAdapter mAdapter;

    public MockWithAdapter(BaseAdapter adapter){
        mAdapter = adapter;
    }

    public List<View> mock(){
        int size = mAdapter.getCount();
        List<View> views = new ArrayList(size);
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
            views.add(mAdapter.getView(i, null, null));

        return views;
    }
}
```

And then you can do with this views whatever you want:

```
MockWithAdapter m = new MockWithAdapter(adapter);
ListView lv = new ListView(context);
for(View v : m.mock)
    lv.addView(v);
```

Comment: That is actually an interesting point, but can you please elaborate with some code so that I can fully understand

Comment: In the presentation by `Romain Guy` and `Adam Powell`, They advice against using a local view cache  http://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/android-world-of-listview-android.pdf

Comment: @GautamK it's just an example. `MockWithAdapter` is pointless. However, as you can see, situation that `parent` null is possible. If you want more real example - here it is: let's assume that you draw each view to separate bitmap (instead of adding them to `ListView`).

Answer (score 0):

### Update 2023 - Kotlin

This is how I did it, inside of `onCreateViewHolder`:

```
class MyAwesomeAdapter constructor(
    private var awesomeList: List<Awesome>,
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAwesomeAdapter.AwesomeViewHolder>() {

    class AwesomeViewHolder(var view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)

    private lateinit var context: Context

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AwesomeViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_awesome, parent, false)

        // SET CONTEXT //
        context = parent.context
        return AwesomeViewHolder(view)
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AwesomeViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val awesome = awesomeList[position]

        holder.apply {

            // Update the UI here or whatever
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = awesomeList.size

    fun update(newAwesomeList: List<Awesome>) {
        awesomeList = newAwesomeList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes but if you need any activity reference like for example dialog alert you cannot use context reference , therefore constructor should receive activity reference from calling Activity/Fragment